Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property CRM_Profile_Page_Dynamic
I have just updated Drupal to 7.101 and Civicrm to 5.66 and now have the following error messages when I log on.Running PHP 8.2 (ea-php82)
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property CRM_Profile_Page_Dynamic::$_isPermissionedChecksum is deprecated in CRM_Profile_Page_Dynamic->run() (line 202 of /home2/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Dynamic.php).
and going to Mailings
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property CRM_Mailing_Form_Search::$_limit is deprecated in CRM_Core_Form_Search->loadStandardSearchOptionsFromUrl() (line 504 of /home2/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form/Search.php).
Should I worry or is there a fix?
